# How do I get images to display in full width on media screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm unable to images to take the the full size of small viewports (max-width:768px) when changing the flex-direction to column.

I Tried changing the container's width to 100% but nothing seems to be working.

I'm still a beginner in Web Dev, Any helpful feedback to this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your CSS and HTML that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

HTML---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Your Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="your-image.jpg" alt="Your Image Description">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS------

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

NOW INSERT THE IMAGE----

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'll do that now , thank you so much.

Comment: please rate me